# Using app folder together with pages folder

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to **Next.JS** and while learning its features I discovered that we are able to put our pages either into `app/` or into `pages/`

I'm a little confused here as I've been told that it's better to use a new `src/app/` folder **instead of** `pages/` folder .

But, I learnt that server components where I use `getInitialProps`, `getStaticProps` with `getStaticPaths` etc. don't work in `app/` router, they return `undefined`. I made a question about this case on Stack Overflow and got an answer that those data fetching methods can be used **ONLY** in `pages/` folder. Moreover, in the **[getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props)**, **[getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)** tutorials, routes in examples are like `pages/index.tsx`

**[From the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)**

> The App Router works in a new directory named app. The app directory works **alongside** the pages directory to allow for incremental adoption. This **allows you to opt some routes of your application into the new behavior while keeping other routes in the pages directory for previous behavior.** If your application uses the pages directory, please also see the Pages Router documentation.

So, as far as I understand, we **can** use `app/` with `pages/` together without any problems. Moreover, I tried to place different routes in both `pages/` and `app/` folder, and they work fine.

Despite my limited understanding, I want to find out if I got it right, or if there is anything I should avoid to build an app the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In general

> [...] or there are any moments I should now to avoid and build project in a right way

There is never a *right* way to build anything in tech. As you stated, yes, "pages" and "app" routers can be used together. Common sense would suggest you only use both when migrating from "pages" to the new "app" router. Elsewise, in a new project, you ought to stick to one router for consistency and interoperability between your pages and components unless you have special circumstances where you need features from both paradigms.

---

> I've been told that it's better to use a new `src/app/` folder instead of `pages/` folder

Neither one is better than the other, they both have strengths and weaknesses. For example, "app router" requires more files and folders which can be overwhelming for large projects however, it supports React Server Components (RSC). In contrast, "pages router" does not support RSC but each file and directory in `pages/` is its own route resulting in a more concise folder structure.

Pick a router which works best for your app. Although "pages" will eventually be sunset, Next has promised to maintain it for a long time.

---

### Regarding data fetching (edit)

From the [Next.js data fetching docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching)

> The Next.js App Router introduces a new, simplified data fetching system built on React and the Web platform. This page will go through the fundamental concepts and patterns to help you manage your data's lifecycle.

The above extract means that `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` and `getInitialProps` will **not** work on the "app router". Instead, you should use RSC to fetch data with the `fetch` function (polyfilled by Next.js for caching) *or* directly fetch data from your data location (usually a database) *within* a RSC. Since RSC, unlike regular client-side components (`"use client";`), are executed on the server they can do everything `getServerSideProps` can.